# How do I save data with chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Say I wanted to make a chrome extension with a text input. Right now, every time I re-open the the extension, the text input clears (does not save what I had last time), but what if I wanted the value in the text input to remain every time I re-opened the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `chrome.storage`.

When the user inputs a value, you save it with:

```
await chrome.storage.local.set({ key: value})
```

You can then retrieve it in background.js every time the user opens the browser again.

See the docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage